# What is the solution with respect to $y(x)$?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

> $$2\cdot \int \{y(x)-t\}\cdot p(x,t)~dt=0$$

**Solution:**
$$y(x)=\frac{\int t\cdot p(x,t)~dt}{p(x)}$$

The solution of this problem is given above. After trying for a while I could not get to the solution. I think product rule of probability should be used but that too didn't lead me to the solution. How can this be solved?

**Note:** Here $p(x)$ and $p(x,t)$ represent probability.

Comment: Do you mean:
$$2\cdot \int \{y(x)-t\}\cdot p(x,t)~dt=0$$
$$y(x)=\frac{\int t\cdot p(x,t)~dt}{p(x)}$$
I'm not sure whether the $2$ is supposed to indicate a question number or if it is part of the equation.

Comment: @projectilemotion the math in your comment is unreadable or it isn't loading properly but I have cross checked and the solution is what I have provided in the picture

Comment: How is it unreadable ? I can read it perfectly. Which browser have you ? Besides, it is not good to give photos instead of writing down formulas.

Comment: @jeanMarie I am using android app and I guess MathJax functions are not working properly so I had provide photo as the integration sign was not loading

Comment: I have placed the formulas written by projectile motion in the text of your question. Can you read them ? If yes, you can cancel the photo.

Comment: Yes now I can read it. Deleted the pic

Comment: @AyushChaurasia On the Android App, you can select the comment, and select the $\vdots$ symbol. Then an option called "Render MathJax" should pop up. Select it, and you should see the formatting.

Comment: 2 questions + a hint for your answer; Question 1 : why the factor 2 ? Question 2) What is $p(x,t) $ a time or space dependent pdf ? Hint: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(x,t)(dx or dt)=1$ for any pdf...

Comment: @projectilemotion I am new to this forum so didn't know it..thanks for telling

Comment: @JeasnMarie oh..I got it..thanks . I didn't think it would be so obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we leave the factor of $2$ aside, the solution comes from separating the integral of the difference by the difference of the integrals, and noting that 
$$\int y(x)p(x,t) dt = y(x) p(x),$$
since $y$ does not depend on $t$ and $\int p(x, t) dt = p(x)$. The last identity is the definition of a [marginal probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) $p(x)$ coming from a [joint probablity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution) $p(x, t)$.

Typically a subscript is used to avoid giving the same notation $p$ to both.